# How can I print to a printer connected to a computer over my LAN

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8, printing, printer

I have a printer connected to one of my computers (computer A).The computer is connected to my LAN. There are two other computers on my LAN (computer B and C). I want to print from computer B and C to my printer.

Computer A runs Windows 7 and computers B and C run Windows 7, 8 and Ubuntu (dual boot).

Comment: it may help if you know what to search for e.g. print over network or better, sharing printer, .  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/share-printer#1TC=windows-7

Comment: well, that worked fine on windows, but i can't make it using ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to make this work: first you need to share your printer on your first computer. Second, you need to connect from your other computers to the printer.

**Share your printer**
There is lots of information about this on the internet and it's quite easy. Right click on your printer icon in the "Devices and Printers" section of your Configuration panel and select "Printer properties". Select the tab "Sharing" and click "Share this printer" and give it a fancy and/or meaningful name.

**Connect to your printer**
From a Windows machine, use the "Add a printer" wizard and let Windows search for your printer.

From Ubuntu, I'd recommend [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu), which has all you need. In short, you need to install [CUPS](https://www.cups.org/). In the menu System -> Administration -> Printing, you can add a printer in a similar way to Windows.

Comment: well, that guide isn't helping me, im stuck with the "find" button, when i put the ip and put find, it says "No printer was found at that address".
i have the pc and the printer on and connected